# finite state or suffix tree

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, suffix-tree

I want to create an algorithm that finds substrings inside a string wich exist in an alphabet. For example in a string "abcdefhhhasddasdabbba" i want to find substrings that are spawned by alphabet {'a','b'}

So my output will be like: ab ,a ,abbba

If I use finite state I have to create exact finite-states that include my outputs so i will have to take all possible combinations in length of my sting input which I do not think it's efficient at all.

If I use suffix tree then how could I find substrings which may not be prefix or post fix inside the tree? Should I use for each node an array that keeps data for the subtree and then check if the array contains characters which are not included in alphabet ?

Edit:

Complexity is crusial.

Comment: The finite-state solution to this problem only requires two states: one for `{a,b}` and one for the rest of the alphabet.

Comment: I think not because if it has only 2 states then as output ill get a ,b ,a ,b ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by trivial loop, no data structures needed.

```
for each letter in word
  if letter in alphabet, then add it to a current "X"
  otherwise emit current "X" and set "X" to empty string
```

python example

```
word = 'aababadadadab'
alphabet = { 'a', 'b' }

X = ''
for letter in word + '$': 
  if letter in alphabet:
    X += letter
  else:
    print X
    X = ''
```

output:

```
aababa
a
a
ab
```

I use '$' as a special character from outside of alphabet, for simplier code

Comment: sorry for the miss-information but i want to do that with the lowest complexity. If i check each letter of the input with each character in the alphabet then the complexity will be like O(n*m) , n:len(input), m:len(alphabet)

Comment: you are wrong. "checking a letter" is O(1) using hash set, so the algoiritm is O(n), the fastest possible.

Comment: With a fixed alphabet, you can also use a bit vector instead of a hash table.

Comment: @larsmans yet you still need a mapping from input characters to bit vector positions, which would require hashing (for O(1) access). So what is the difference ?

Comment: @lejlot You don't need to hash anything, just use the character code as an index. (That won't be practical for full Unicode, but for smaller alphabets it's faster and simpler.)

Comment: This is exactly the same as using a hashtable with identity hashing and size of the maximum code :)